# Valgrind output does not show function names in its output

Tags: c++, valgrind

```
==24145== Thread 2:
==24145== Invalid read of size 8
==24145==    at 0x462E2E: ??? (in <path of binary>)
==24145==    by 0x4649B4: ??? (in <path of binary>)
==24145==    by 0x467E7D: ??? (in <path of binary>)
==24145==    by 0x455302: ??? (in <path of binary>)
==24145==    by 0x45B830: ??? (in <path of binary>)
==24145==    by 0x4E633A: ??? (in <path of binary>)
==24145==    by 0x4E5FC1: ??? (in <path of binary>)
==24145==    by 0x743ADC4: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==24145==    by 0x7745C4C: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==24145==  Address 0x488 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

It shows ??? instead of function names. (I have removed path of binary by myself).

Comment: I used these options : valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes -v --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --show-reachable=yes --leak-resolution=high --num-callers=100 --log-file="seg_fault_2.txt"

Comment: Did you build with debug information? (`-g` if you're using g++.)

Comment: update your question with basic information. Let us know what you do... instead of spamming code first and us puzzle what it is you actually want. Also your commented information should be in your question as information and not in comment. Its kinda relevant.

Comment: did you compile with 'g++ -static -g'?  aslo good to use  --track-origins=yes

Comment: Build was not with -g (debug) option. So that might be the issue. Thanks,